# List from Javascript to Post Method c#

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi everyone i have a problem on javascript for pass the list from the result of form to post method in c#.
Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $('#runProcess').click(function() {

    var request = new WebPay();// is only a method where i take the result from the fiel of the form 
    var list = new Array();
    list.push(JSON.stringify(request));
    var jsonstr = {'':list};

    $.ajax({
              type: "POST"
              url: "http://localhost:4556/Pay_Info"
              datatype: "JSON",
              data: jsonstr,
              traditional: true,
              success:function (data,textStatus, jqHr){
              //build a grid with jquery
```

The post method is :

public HttpResponseMessage Pay_Info([FromBody] List Pay)

The fields are good i mean when i take the result from a form i have the right Json String but when i pass the array (list) in the post method the fields are empty i mean  i have only the default fields of the form and not my json string result. The problem is when i pass the array to the post method.
Can you help me ??

Comment: `type = "text7javascript"` is completely wrong.

Comment: what is `List Pay`? it your custom type?

Comment: why is wrong text/javascript ?? i have one that is the same and work ... list pay is my custom type ...

Answer (score 0):

```
list.push(JSON.stringify(request));
var jsonstr = {'':list};
```

You can not have object with empty key.make it like

```
list.push(request);
var jsonstr = JSON.stringify(list);
```

Comment: I tried but with {'':list} in the post method i have the default fields of the form in my case two date and one number:
1/1/0001
1/1/0001
null
In your case in the variable Pay of the post ethod i have null

Comment: can you show your post method for which ajax request is made.

Comment: @GMG are you try `var jsonstr = {Key:list};` or `var jsonstr = {"Pay":list};`?

Comment: @Grundy yes it should be Pay

Comment: @ akhlesh My post method has response you know HttpResponseMessage with a list of result but the problem is when i debug the variable in input of the post method is with default fields when i have the correct jsonstring in javascript

Comment: @Grundy i tried both the way and for the  {key:list} the Pay variable in the post method is a list and count 0, with {"Pay":list} is null

Comment: list.push(request);
    var jsonstr =JSON.stringify(list);

try this.

Comment: Hey guy i tried again all your solutions but don't work ... i don't know

Answer (score 0):

So with:
                     var list = new Array();
                     list.push(JSON.stringify(request));
                     var jsonstr = { '' : list };

```
                 $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "http://localhost:4556/Pay_Info",
                     dataType: "json",
                     data: jsonstr,
                     traditional: true,
```

something pass in the post method but the fields are with default values and not with my json string value. When i debug the count of the list is 1

With:

```
                    list.push(request);
                    var jsonstr = JSON.stringify(list);

                     $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "http://localhost:4556/Pay_Info",
                     dataType: "json",
                     data: jsonstr,
                     traditional: true,
```

In the list of post method the count was 0 and nothing pass
With:

var jsonstr = {Key:list}; or var jsonstr = {"Pay":list};

The count of the list in post method is 0 so nothing is passed